# Beginner - Qt - QMouseEvent (right click) - Signal and Slots

Tags: qt, mouseevent, signals-slots

I want to make an event on a `QPushbutton` object that its text changed when I right-clicked on it.

Answer (score 2):

Use QPushButton's mousepress event like this

```
::mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * e )
{
    if( e->button() == Qt::RightButton )
    {
     ...
     ...
    }
}
```